# How to disable WPA1 security and keep only WPA2-AES wifi hotspot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, wireless-access-point, wpa2, wpa

WPA1 is not secure I want to keep only WPA2-AES.

WHen I run `nmcli device wifi list`  I get message below:

```
IN-USE  SSID  MODE   CHAN  RATE      SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       na    Infra  1     0 Mbit/s  0       ____  WPA1 WPA2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo nmcli con modify "Wi-Fi Hot" 802-11-wireless-security.proto rsn
```

will disable WPA1 and leave WPA2/rsn active.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to remove WPA1 but I was able to block TKIP which is not secure, by setting WPA2-AES = pairwise ccmp

```
sudo nmcli con modify "Wi-Fi Hot" 802-11-wireless-security.pairwise ccmp
sudo service network-manager restart
```

ref: https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Wifi_NetworkManager#Configuring_WiFi_Access_Point